# how to get the client id of Text box inside the grid using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> i have a editable Gridview(containing 7 editable fields/textbox in each row)  in which i have a text box and i am
>   calling JS function but i am not getting the client id if the text box
>   inside Grideview is there any way to do it ?
>   GEIDVIEW -> [image: GRID]

```
  <asp:TemplateField>  <EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txCTFact" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CT_Factor") %>' Width="50px" onchange="validateCTfactor(this);" />  
</EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

> JS  locally i was doing it by

```
text = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txCTFact').value;
```

> but in different browser it's getting different client id is there any
>   generic way.

```
 function validateCTfactor(val) {
            var v = val.id.split('_')[1];
            var text = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txCTFact').value;
            var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$");
            if (re.test(text)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Required Field with Only numbers allowed with 1 decimal place in CT Factor");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function validateCTfactor(val) 
{ 

    var text = val.value;
 var re = new RegExp("^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$");
 if (re.test(text))
 { return true; } 
else 
{
 alert("Required Field with Only numbers allowed with 1 decimal place in CT Factor"); 
return false; 
}
 }
```

You can directly fetch the value of textbox by `val.value`. No need for it's  `id`.

For getting id of each textbox inside grid:

```
    $("#gridId input:text").each(
              function ()
             {
                alert ($(this).prop("id"));
             }
);
```

Comment: by that i am not getting id/value of the textboxes of that row i want to edit

Comment: Did you debug your code in browser? What exactly are you getting?

Comment: is there any way to get the id of all the textbox inside grid

Comment: You can use Jquery for that

Comment: can't do that JS ?

Comment: Maybe it's possible but it's much simpler using Jquery